# More HD space after ubuntu instalation

Tags: installation, filesystem

I am a newby user with ubuntu 11.10, and I have instaled it with windows installer. I like this and I want to do the ubuntu filesystem more bigger. ¿Anyone know how can I do?

Thanks a lot, 
Eder

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow instructions from [Wubi Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_resize_the_virtual_disks.3F), or, specifically, this [howto](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1625371)